# How to createID and pick latest n entries from the set in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

in golang how to use user generated id and increment it for every new entry? I tried

> ```
>   Index(KpiIndex).
>       Type(KpiDocType).
>       Id(ids).                                                              => Id will take only stings.
>       BodyJson(kpis).
>       Do(elasticSearchContext)
> ```

And when data is getting stored in ES, it is getting stored in randomly say

> {
>     "took" : 5,
>     "timed_out" : false,
>     "_shards" : {
>       "total" : 5,
>       "successful" : 5,
>       "failed" : 0
>     },
>     "hits" : {
>       "total" : 4,
>       "max_score" : 1.0,
>       "hits" : [
>         {
>           "_index" : "kpi",
>           "_type" : "kpi",
>           "_id" : "AWIexPLwnbh5r7Xr9nsL",
>           "_score" : 1.0,
>           "_source" : {
>             "date" : "2018-03-13 15:20:45",
>             "kpi" : [
>               {
>
> ```
>           "Static_limit" : 0
>         },
>         {
>           "CpuAverageLoad" : 0,
>           ...,
>           "NodeType" : "kkk",
>           "State" : "online"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "_index" : "kpi",
>     "_type" : "kpi",
>     "_id" : "AWIexYy1_xnN0Y7Qo1HE",
>     "_score" : 1.0,
>     "_source" : {
>       "date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:25",
>       "kpi" : [
>         {
>           "CpuAverageLoad" : 0,
>           },
>         {
>           "CpuAverageLoad" : 0,
>           ...,
>           "NodeType" : "kkk",
>           "State" : "online"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "_index" : "kpi",
>     "_type" : "kpi",
>     "_id" : "AWIexdrLnbh5r7Xr9nsM",
>     "_score" : 1.0,
>     "_source" : {
>       "date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:45",
>       "kpi" : [
>         {
>
>           "Static_limit" : 0
>         },
>         {
>           "CpuAverageLoad" : 0,
>           ...,
>           "NodeType" : "kkk",
>           "State" : "online"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   },
>   {
>     "_index" : "kpi",
>     "_type" : "kpi",
>     "_id" : "AWIexT52BjtG8JuPSysx",
>     "_score" : 1.0,
>     "_source" : {
>       "date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:05",
>       "kpi" : [
>         {
>
>           "Static_limit" : 0
>         },
>         {
>           "CpuAverageLoad" : 0,
>           ...,
>           "NodeType" : "kkk",
>           "State" : "online"
>         }
>       ]
>     }
>   }
> ]
> ```
>
> }
>   }

When we observe the 'data' field, the order is

```
"date" : "2018-03-13 15:20:45",
"date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:25",
"date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:45",
"date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:05",
```

where as the correct order should be

```
"date" : "2018-03-13 15:20:45",
"date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:05",
"date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:25",
"date" : "2018-03-13 15:21:45"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a property into json body which value will be GUID. Hence, define the property as an _id property. Its the way for define index id.